# Base64 decode becomes weird text

Tags: encryption, hash, base64, sha256

I am trying something new with base64. The sha-256(base64) method. It has an output to base64 so I thought I can just decode it to base64. Well then it becomes this, � ��a�bcfVx&� zS�JZ����#�5�. Is there like no way to decode that type of base64 or even a hash because it hash sha-256? This is the original hash: viAQv+m8YcpiY2ZWeCYOtCAcelPjSlq3kaO+I801D7w=

This is just to get to know more about hashing and data security. I know what the output of the original hash was but I just want to train my knowledge.

Is there any way to decrypt this? Thanks in advance.

PS: I also tried to go to hexidecimal first and then it gave me this, � ���a�bcfVx&� zS�JZ����#�5�

Please help.

Comment: The output you're getting is the 256-bit hash (from SHA-256). It is displayed this way because you're printing it directly (as a string). Try printing the bytes in hexadecimal or something similar.

Comment: If you want the result in a form that you can copy and paste around then just keep it in the base64 encoding.  That is the point of base64.

Comment: What is this "sha-256(base64) method" you're referring to? If you want a hash value, just use sha-256. There isn't much point combining it with base64 encoding, and since it's a hash function, it is going to be impossible to decrypt. (Also, why did you add a PS containing the exact same unicode garbage as the first paragraph of your question?)

Comment: Consider accepting answers that are helpful. By accepting a answer you are indicating to future readers that it is a correct answer.

To accept an answer click on the hollow checkmark next to the answer that is best, doing so will increase your reputation and allow more capabilities, See [reputation faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation)  See [this page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more detail.

Answer (score 2):

SHA-256, cryptographic functions in general, produce sequence of binary bytes, not displayable characters.

When it is necessary to have a displayable version the data is generally encoded to Base64 or hexadecimal. Decoding back to binary produces many un-displayable bytes.

When one tries to display bytes with non-displayable values ofter a place holder glyph such as � is displayed.